# Woher kommt "pfiat di"/"pfiat eich" als Abschiedsformel im bayerischen Raum?

Tags: etymology, usage, phrase, bavarian, valediction

Im südöstlichen deutschsprachigen Raum, genauer: im Bairischen Sprachraum (Bayern, Österreich {ausser Vorarlberg und Ausserfern/Reutte/Tirol} und Südtirol), teilweise noch in Bairisch-Schwaben gebräuchlich (Oberallgäu), ist "pfiat di" bzw. "pfiat eich" eine übliche Grußformel zum Abschied.

Edit: Auch im Raum Ausserfern ist -trotz alemannischem Einfluss - „Pfiat di“ oder „Pfiat enk“ eine übliche und gängige Grußformel.

Was bedeutet sie bzw. woher kommt sie (etymologisch gesehen)?

Comment: Südöstlich, nicht südlich. In Baden-Württemberg und der Schweiz ist das völlig ungebräuchlich, in Franken vermutlich ebenso. Im österreichischen Bairisch dagegen schon. Kurz: "Pfiat di" ist ein bairischer Dialektgruß. Die vermutliche Etymologie ist übrigens [im Online-Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pfiat) erklärt.

Comment: Ich möchte ergänzen, dass gerade dieser Gruß häufig gemeinsam mit einer grammatischen Rarität, dem Dual https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(Grammatik) verwendt wird: »Pfiat enk« wenn man sich von einem Paar (also zwei zusammengehörenden Personen) verabschiedet.

Comment: Im bayerischen Bairisch wird *enk* aber auch ganz allgemein als Ersatz für *ihr* verwendet; wenn man sich also von einer Gruppe (auch mehr als zwei Leute) verabschiedet, die man duzt, würde man *pfiats enk(ch)* sagen.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In der langen Version würde man sagen:

> Pfüat di Gott

was so viel heißt wie "Gott behüte Dich".

In der originalen Reihenfolge (Kommentar teylyn) "Behüt Dich Gott", verkürzt zu *B'hüt di Gott*.

Nachzulesen im [Bairischen Wörterbuch](http://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/buchstabe-p/) und auch bei den Grimms unter [behüten](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB02851#XGB02851).

Comment: ...und ich hatte immer geglaubt, es hieße "Gott führe dich"...

Comment: Und bhüt di wird zu Pfüidi. Interessanter Lautwandel von b+h zu pf und ü + i (nächster Silbe) zu üi oder ü+schwaches e.

Comment: Könnte es nicht auch von "befehlen" kommen? (Psalm 37: *...befiehl dem Herrn deine Wege...*)

Comment: Dann hätte es ja ursprünglich "Befehle dich Gott" geheißen, was weit weniger sinnvoll wäre. (Aber was heißt schon sinnvoll, wir sagen ja auch Grüß Gott.)

Comment: @sgf Grüß Gott: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BC%C3%9F_Gott

Comment: Man sollte auch wissen, daß Bayerisch mundfaul und tiefenentspannt ist, darum ist der Butter auch männlich (da Buda), weil die weibliche Form schwerer auszusprechend ist (d'Buda) -- hawadere

Answer (score 8):

> bhiad di god -> pfiad di god

Bh wird zu einem Laut zusammengezogen: *piad*. Wikipedia (zweite Lautverschiebung): *"Die Verschiebung von /p/ → /pf/ erscheint im gesamten Oberdeutschen."* (Oberdeutsch sind, sehr grob gesagt, die deutschen Dialekte mit Ursprung aus dem Gebiet von Baden-Württemberg und Bayern bis Südtirol).

Beispiel: engl. hemp <-> bairisch Hampf <-> deutsch Hanf

Ich schätze, hier hat sich die gleiche Entwicklung vollzogen, was den Ausdruck *pfiadi* womöglich bis ins Frühmittelalter zurückreichen lässt.
Das ist alles nur Spekulation. Ohne es mehrfach nachzuschauen, hätte ich keine Ahnung, was *pfiad* heißt.

Answer (score 0):

Ich weiß, es wird überall so erklärt, dass „pfiat/pfiad/pfia/pfir“ von „bhiad“ kommt.
Wobei wohl alle aus einer Quelle abgeschrieben haben und es – ohne nachzudenken und zu prüfen – weiterverbreiten … (Die nichtnachdenkende und nicht-quellenangebende Kopierer-Gemeinde ist erschreckend riesig!)

Die Erklärung meines Vorredners **scheint** schlüssig – scheint aber nur. 
Denn in Bayern wird man mit „Pfiat di Gott“ **oder** mit „B’hi(a)t di Gott“ verabschiedet.
Wobei ich schon auf einer Ortsausgangstafel „Fiat Enk Gott“ gesehen habe! (Vermutlich war das in Österreich.)

Die als Grund angegebene Lautverschiebung vom Englischen ins Bairische (?!?) ist aber gewaltig an den Haaren herbeigezogen... Und in „Bayrisches Wörterbuch“ (Webseite von einer Privatperson betrieben) ist doch keine sichere bzw. wissenschaftliche Quelle! Auch Wikipedia ist schon lange keine sichere Quelle mehr … leider.

Meines Erachtens nach kommt es von „Führe dich Gott“.
Das ergibt im Dialekt: „Fia di Gott“ bzw. "Fir di Gott".
Und von da ist es sprachlich nicht weit zum „Pfia di Gott“ – in Oberbayern auch ausgesprochen: „Pfir di Gott“!

Und wenn ich mir dann so einen Bauern mit seinem Pfeifchen im Mund vorstelle, wie er
„Fia/Fir di Gott“ sagt …

Vielleicht findet sich ja noch in einem alten Buch der Ursprung dieser segensreichen Verabschiedung … :-)
Bis dahin: Pfiats eich Gott! :-)

Comment: Hast du dazu eine Quelle?

Comment: Was für eine Lautverschiebung vom Englischen ins Bairische denn?

Comment: Vielleicht ist das "alte Buch", aus dem alle abschreiben, Grimms Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache? Ich habe mal in meiner Antwort noch den Link dazu gesetzt.

Comment: Du schreibst: *»Und von da ist es sprachlich nicht weit zum „Pfia di Gott“«*. Das stimmt aber nicht. Der Weg in die umgekehrte Richtung (von *»pf«* zu *»f«*) ist schnell gegangen, aber das ist eine Einbahnstraße. *»pf«* kommt nur in sehr wenigen Sprachen vor uns ist sehr schwer auszusprechen. Es gibt Millionen Menschen mit Deutsch als Muttersprache, die »Ferd« statt »Pferd« sagen, weil sie das *»pf«* nicht hinkriegen. Kinder können *»f«* schon mit ca 2 1/2 Jahren aussprechen, aber *»pf«* geht (wenn überhaupt) erst ein ganzes Jahr später.

Comment: Der Weg führt (im historisch gut belegten Lautwandel) von *»p«* zu *»pf«* und dann in vielen Fällen weiter zu *»f«*. Mir ist kein einziger Fall bekannt, wo eine Verschiebung in die umgekehrte Richtung stattgefunden hätte.

Comment: Den besserwissern in den Kommentaren ist schon klar, dass von "Pehüten" zu reden etwas Monthy Python haftes, unfreiwillig Homisches hat. Diese Antwort zeigt doch, dass es relativ wahrscheinlich ist, dass eine Verwechslung mit *führen* relativ weite Verbreitung gefunden hat und hier also zumindest nicht unterschlagen werden darf.

Answer (score 0):

"Pfiat (pfüad) di Gott" (oder "Pföit di Gott"  in der Oberpfalz) 
ist ein Abschiedsgruß und bedeutet "Behüt Dich Gott!"
Alles andere ist an den Haaren herbeigezogen.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Ich würde es konstruktiver finden, die Kritik an anderen Herleitungstheorien mehr objektiver zu schreiben - oder ganz weglassen. Ist das eine Option?

Answer (score -1):

**Meines Erachtens kommt es von „Führe dich Gott“.
Das ergibt im Dialekt: „Fia di Gott“ bzw. "Fir di Gott".
Und von da ist es sprachlich nicht weit zum „Pfia di Gott“ – in Oberbayern auch ausgesprochen: „Pfir di Gott“!**

Dazu möchte ich etwas anmerken:
Im Österreichischen sagt man umgangssprachlich für "ich freue mich" "i gfrei mi" – für meine österreichischen Ohren klingt's mit dem extra "g" harmonischer. Ich habe kurz recherchiert, in der Linguistik nennt man das, wie es scheint, "Prothese".

Demnach erscheint es für mich logisch, dass aus "fia di gott" "pfia di gott" wurde; für mich klingt es harmonischer, Stichwort Satzmelodie. Mein Opa (Baujahr 1940) sagt zur Verabschiedung immer "pfiazi" – weiß aber nicht warum. Vielleicht eine Art sprachliche Verschleifung?

Comment: Dein Argument würde für »gfia di got« sprechen. Das ist aber nicht zu hören.

Comment: Das wäre es, ja, wenn du nicht das Prinzip hinter meiner Aussage, sondern mein Beispiel 1:1 auf das des OTs umlegen würdest.

Als Veranschaulichung: Du hast zwei Flaschen mit je 2L. In der einen ist ein halber Liter, in der anderen 1 Liter, du sollst beide füllen. Du gießt 1,5L in die erste Flasche, die Flasche ist voll - das bedeutet *nicht* dass du bei der zweiten Flasche ebenfalls 1,5L brauchst, es sind *in diesem Fall* 1L. 

Jetzt verstanden?

Comment: für meine Berliner Ohren klingt's eher wie Rebracketing (neuklammerung?). Ick mein dit klingt wie "ickfreu ma"

Comment: vectory (hab deine antwort grad eben zufällig entdeckt): zu dem rebracketing / neuklammerung find ich irgendwie nichts vernünftiges, hast du zufällig ein(e) PDF / paper / dissertation / o.ä.?

Answer (score -2):

"Pfia di" käme am ehesten von "Der Segen Gottes für Euch" Endsegen des Priesters nach der Messe. Antwort des Volkes war eigenlich gewöhnlich nur Amen. Stand der Pfarrer aber am Ausgang der Kirche und verabschiedete sich von dem freien Bauern persönlich, war diesen Antwort: "Für auch dich" = "pfi a di". Davon angelehnt haben begonnen besonders wenn Bauer und Knechte zu gefährlichen Arbeiten loszogen, dass Mütter ihnen Gottes Segen wünschten. Pfiadi Gott meint also : auch für dich Gottes Segen. Dabei ist anzumerken, dass alle Ableitungen immer auf den Segenswunsch enden, egal ob von behüte dich,führe dich oder für dich stammt.

Comment: Sorry, aber das ist einfach nur falsch. Deine Erklärungsversuch fußt auf der Behauptung »für → pfi«. Und das ist völlig aus der Luft gegriffen. Der bairische Dialektausdruck für »für« ist »fia«. Wo bitte soll das *P* herkommen? Außerdem ist auch der Satzbau von »für auch dich« falsch. Das stimmt weder mit hochdeutscher noch mit bayrischer Grammatik überein. Das müsste hochdeutsch entweder »auch für dich« oder »für dich auch« heißen, und im Dialekt wäre das dann entweder »a fia di« oder »fia di a«. Aber ganz  egal wie man das dreht oder wendet: Da kommt nirgendwo ein *P* vor!

Answer (score -2):

Pfia di heisst "fürchte dich", welches bedeutet "fürchte dich vor Gott", aus dem mittelalterlichen christlichen Glauben des übermächigen und zuweilen zornigen Gottes.

Comment: Damit widersprichst du der Antwort von Takkat, der seine Version mit zwei renommierten Quellen belegen konnte. Du stellst hier nur eine Behauptung in den Raum, ohne sie irgendwie zu belegen. Bitte liefere glaubhafte und nachprüfbare Belege nach.

Answer (score -4):

Ich könnte mir noch vorstellen, dass es mit dem Pförtner an der Himmelstür zu tun hat. Quasi "mögest du gepförtnert werden".

1) Aus religiös geprägter Sprache, also der Wunsch, es möge/n dem/n Beglückwünschten am Himmelstor Einlass gewährt werden.
2) Als Abschied banaler, mündliche Begleitung zum Akt des vor die Türe setzen.
3) Als Glückwunsch bis zum (ungewissen) Wiedersehen, wie "es sollen Dir alle Türen aufgehen".

Comment: Das *ö* in *Pförtner* würde zu einem *ä*-Laut werden; das *r* könnte in großer Nähe zum Allgäu auch als *r* verbleiben und nicht vokalisiert/diphthongisiert werden. *Pfia Gott* enthält aber eindeutig einen *i* Laut – das könnte also höchstens ein *ü* sein *(Pfürtner?),* und ein konsonantisch verbleibendes *r* höre ich selbst im Allgäu nicht heraus.

Answer (score -4):

I think it's a leftover from the days of Roman occupation. Fiat di seems to be used as a brusque but friendly brush-off parting, simply expressing "OK, I'm done with you. Good-bye" I believe that after watching how the phrase is commonly used in Bavaria. Sometimes it is said with kind and loving attitude, of course, but it is also often used as a clear closure to an interaction, as from a waitress or store keeper, as in, "our transaction is done." There is nothing about Fiat or the Bavaricized version, Pfiad, that sounds anything like most of the words that people have speculated are roots of this. If it was from Fuhrt or Behut or whatnot, there would be likely some neighborhood somewhere in southern Europe where you could still recognize something more similar to the actual root. I think the actual root is the actual current word, fiat, in Italian. It means "Let it be done" as described in this reference in Wikipedia (sorry, I know some of you don't like Wikipedia, but just because a speaker makes some mistakes, does not mean that the speaker has nothing valuable to teach you.) The term fiat derives from the Latin fiat ("let it be done")[8] used in the sense of an order, decree[2] or resolution.[9]   [8] Fiat is the third-person singular present active subjunctive of fiō ("I become", "I am made"). [9] Schueffel, Patrick (2017). The Concise Fintech Compendium. Fribourg: School of Management Fribourg/Switzerland. Archived from the original on October 24, 2017.

So fiat di is simply "let it be done/resolved with you", just as fiat eich or fiat euch is, likewise. So fiat is from the Italian/Roman, and di and euch, from the German/Bavarian.

Comment: This answer combines an impressive surface (without references, however) with a more than debatable (if not even wrong) content. I fail to see, what *Fintech Compendium* can contribute here.