# Woher kommt der Ausdruck "Teita gehen"?

Tags: etymology, baby-talk

Ich habe gerade festgestellt, dass meine Kollegen diesen Ausdruck auch kennen, aber unterschiedlich benutzen.

Die mir vertraute Bedeutung ist, ein Kleinkind zu einem Spaziergang aufzufordern (was zwei andere Kollegen auch so kennen). Ein anderer Kollege benutzt diesen Ausdruck allerdings, wenn er mit seinem Hund spazieren geht.

Gibt es irgendeinen Ursprung, der die Verknüpfung von *Teita* mit *spazieren* erklärt?

Comment: +1 Sehr interessante Frage! Ich habe es von meiner schwäbischen Mutter als "adda gehen" kennengelernt.

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt habe ich den Ausdruck noch nie gehört. Bei uns hört man manchmal "Spatz gehen" (eher mit dem Hund als mit einem Kind)

Comment: Ich kenne aus meiner Kindheit "Atta atta gehen" (eher mit stimmlosem "t" als mit stimmhaftem "d"), und das hieß auch soviel wie "spazieren gehen". Einige Quellen im Internet - einfaches googeln genügt - weisen auf dieselben Wurzeln wie "Teita" hin. Der Ausdruck wurde allerdings von meinen Eltern als nicht förderlich für die Erziehung abgelehnt - irgendwie weiß ich das noch. Ein möglicher etymologischer Zusammenhang würde mich auch interessieren.

Comment: Aus welcher Gegend stammen Sie? Wo wird der Ausdruck verwendet? Er ist mir völlig unbekannt und ich hätte auch nicht im Traum daran gedacht, es mit spazieren gehen zu assoziieren (egal ob mit Hund oder Balg). Auch "adda / atta / Spatz gehen" sind mir völlig fremd. Es scheint mir regionale Kindersprache zu sein. Leute, die das zu mir sagen (Kollegen) würde ich nicht mehr ernst nehmen.

Comment: Ich lebe im Sauerland. Übrigens habe ich mit keinem Wort gesagt dass Kollegen das zu mir gesagt hätten, nur dass sie diesen Ausdruck auch kennen.

Comment: Bei uns in Gelsenkirchen hat man auch Teita gehen gesagt. Das war Anfang der 50-er.

Comment: Noch nie gehört. Wird auf jeden Fall nicht in Niederösterreich verwendet.

Comment: Wir in Osnabrück (Niedersachsen) verwenden den Ausdruck *teita gehen* :-) aber eigentlich nur zu kleinen Kindern.

Comment: Ich, Niederländer, habe den Begriff "Teita gehen" auch schon öfter gehört, hier im Ruhrgebiet. Klingt tatsächlich wie Kindersprache, wie "in die Heia gehen" oder "Heia machen" (für schlafen).

Comment: „Tata gehen“ kenne ich auch hier am Niederrhein noch von früher...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vermutlich hat auch *"Teita"* seine Wurzel in dem Gruß *"[Adieu](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=adieu)"* (hergeleitet von *lat. "ad deum"*). *Ad deum*, bzw. *Ad dei* wurde dann als Lallwort (in Analogie zu einem **Onomatopoetikon**) in der Kindersprache zu *"Teita"*, *"Atta"*, *"Adda"* oder *"Ta-Ta"*.

*"Teita gehen"* bedeutet dann so viel wie "sich mit einem Gruß (zu einem Spaziergang) zu verabschieden."

Im Übrigen finden wir diese Herkunft etymologisch oder sinngemäß auch in anderen geläufigen Grußformeln wie *"Tschüss"*, *"Ade"*, *"Grüß Gott"*, *"[Pfiat di](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/254/woher-kommt-pfiat-di-pfiat-eich-als-abschiedsformel-im-bayerischen-raum)"* und weiteren.

Comment: @WalterTross: aber *Tschüss* kommt, über ein paar Zwischenstationen, von *Adieu*. In einigen Teilen von Holland sagen wir *Ajuus* (ausgesprochen *ajüs*), auch abgeleitet von *Adieu*.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis im ursprünglichen Text dieser Antwort war _Tschau_ fälschlicherweise unter den mit _Adieu_ verwandten Grußformeln aufgezählt, daher mein Kommentar.

Comment: @WalterTross: deshalb ist es eine gute Idee, Kommentare zu löschen, wenn sie nicht mehr benötigt werden (damals war ich noch kein Mod) ;)

Comment: Übrigens, kommt "à Dieu" nicht eher aus dem Französischen? OK, das kommt dann ursprünglich aus dem Lateinischen, aber Adieu selbst?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: ganz richtig, man kann das im obigen Link zu Adieu bei DWDS genauer nachlesen, ich habe das vielleicht etwas knapp zusammengefasst.

Answer (score 3):

Könnte aus dem Russischen kommen. Weggehen = отойти (gesprochen ataiti). Bedeutungen im Russischen auch starten, abfahren, gehen, sich entfernen, abgehen etc. und könnte Quelle sowohl des kindersprachlichen "Atta gehen" als auch "Teita gehen" sein.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Gibt es außer der Übersetzung von "weggehen" noch weitere - oder schlicht etwas mehr ausgeführte - Argumente finden, die diese These stützen? Z.B. welches "weggehen" damit gemeint ist, im Deutschen gibt es da verschiedene Bedeutungen, russisch kann ich nicht.

Comment: Klingt gut. Bitte soweit möglich in die Antwort integrieren. (edit-button).

Answer (score 2):

Es kommt wie so Vieles aus dem Griechischen. Teita oder Tita ist im Griechischen eh das Gleiche, da ei = i ist, wobei dies in manchen gegenden auch Tata-Gehen genannt wird. Taschi-tita ist die Geschwindigkeit, wobei Taschino die Beschleunigung ist.
Tita sagt also, dass der Spaziergang eines Erwachsenen für das Kind mit Beschleunigung bzw. schnellen gehen. Deshalb laufen Kinder automatisch immer ein wenig neben Erwachsenen.

Comment: PS: Das Russische ist daher auchaus dem Griechischen abzuleiten