# Woher kommt »Ata gehen«?

Tags: etymology, baby-talk

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ata) ist *ata gehen* Kindersprache für *spazieren gehen,* aber was bedeutet *ata* eigentlich und woher stammt es? Auch die Kindersprache nimmt ja meist Ausdrücke aus anderen Quellen und verzerrt diese.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2619/woher-kommt-der-ausdruck-teita-gehen

Comment: Ich kenne nur "adda gehen" aus dem Schwäbischen - Und ich denke, dass es in der Kindersprache daher kommt, weil man "Ade" sagt, wenn man aus dem Haus geht.

Comment: So klar ist es nicht, dass damit »Spazieren gehen« gemeint ist. Ich habe diesen Begriff bis gerade eben noch nie in meinem Leben gehört oder gelesen. (Ich lebe im Osten Österreichs.) Mit Ata verbinde ich ausschließlich das: https://www.saymo.de/documents/image/33/33117/33117.jpg »Ata gehen« hätte daher für mich - bis eben jetzt - absolut keinen Sinn ergeben.

Comment: Ich habe in "ata gehen" auch ich im Leben noch nicht gehört. Wo kommt das her? :)

Comment: mit "ada" hätte ich das auch noch nie gehört, aber hier in Ostösterreich sagt man in der Kindersprache "baba gehen" zum "Weggehen" von einem Ort ´, speziell wenn damit eine Verabschiedung verbunden ist. "baba" steht in der Kindersprache fürs "auf Wiedersehen sagen", oftmals verbunden mit Winken.

Comment: Ich kenne eher die Variante "teita". Ich vermute mal, die sind sich ähnlich, oder haben eine ähnliche Entstehungsgeschichte. Soll von "Ad Deum" kommen, also von Adé, Tschüß, Adieu, usw.

Comment: @Hubert: dein Link funktioniert nicht: 404.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Neuer Link: https://www.idealclean.de/ata-scheuerpulver-reinigungspulver-500-g-dose.html

Comment: @Hubert: Danke. Also doch ATA "sanft und sauber". <g>

Answer (score 5):

Es ist ein kleinkindsprachlicher Ausdruck, entstanden entweder aus der Abschiedsformel »adieu« (in der Form »adé«) oder durch Abschleifung aus »Tag-Tag machen« im Sinne von »zum Abschied winken« (19.Jh.).<sup>[(1)](http://umgangssprache_de.deacademic.com/575/ada)</sup><sup>[(2)](http://www.heinrich-tischner.de/22-sp/9sp-ecke/artikel/200/2005/05-08-23.htm)</sup>

Comment: variiert je nach Region. Z.B. "auf die tata gehen" in Thüringen.

Answer (score 4):

Spazieren ist für Kleinkinder zu schwieirg auszusprechen, daher legen sie den Focus auf das A at...und kürzen es mit einem a gleich wieder ab...ata......ich kann mich nämlich daran erinnern :-) und meine schwester hiess Tata....von kerstin.....viel zu schwer, also terstin? nein, aus er bei Ter wird a und abgekürzt wird wieder mit einem a....kerstin-Tata....logisch!

Answer (score 2):

Der Begriff "ata ata gehen" war und ist in Berlin seit ewigen Zeiten ein sehr gebräuchlicher Ausdruck für das spazieren gehen mit kleinen Kindern.

Wird heute eher selten gebraucht und dann auch nur von echten! Berlinern.

Ansatzweise könnte man auch versuchen, diesen Ausdruck [onomatopoetisch zu klären oder herzuleiten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoesie).

Mit dem Putzmittel hat das nichts zu tun.

Answer (score -2):

. in berlin zumindest , im alten berlin, gab es einen zusammenhang . . . denn die mütter haben in erster linie einen omnibus benützt . . . um ins grüne zu fahren . . . bzw. erledigungen zu machen . . . und auf eben diesen bussen stand geschrieben : "ATA ATA" . . . – Manfred Rühl 14 mins ago
[image]

Comment: @raznagul: Ich würde die Antwort nicht so ganz ernst nehmen. Das Bild ist schön. <g>

Comment: Bitte editiere die Antwort und füge die Erklärung ein. Das Bild alleine erklärt hier garnichts.

Comment: . . . gemacht . . .

Comment: @ManfredRühl: das macht die Antwort leider nicht besser, denn das Scheuermittel ATA gibt es erst seit 1920, der Ausdruck *ata gehen* ist jedoch schon in Lexika des 19. Jahrhunderts belegt. Allenfalls könnte man spekulieren, dass Henkel den Begriff adoptiert hatte (Schmutz soll ata gehen), aber auch das wäre reichlich an den Haaren herbei gezogen.

Comment: Kindersprache heißt hier ja auch Kleinkindersprache, also solche, die noch nicht richtig sprechen können. Lesen können die natürlich erst recht nicht, auch nicht 1920, obwohl früher alles viel besser war.

Comment: Interessanterweise kenn ich den Ausdruck "ata ata imi imi". Vielleicht ist da ja was dran.