# Seit wann sagt man „Popo“?

Tags: history

[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB09431#XGB09431) schreibt:

> BOBO, m. podex, mit dem ton auf der letzten silbe, ein in der sprache der ammen, mädchen, mütter allgemein übliches wort, traulicher als der hintere oder steisz, feiner als arsch, und in der rede gebildeter verwendbar, in den wörterbüchern aber fehlend (nur Campe und Heyse geben popo, **doch niemand spricht so**, Castelli im östr. wb. 89 boboh); wahrscheinlich auch der nnl. dän. und schw. sprache bekannt. auf den bobo fallen; sich auf den bobo setzen; den bobo klitschen; schläge auf den bobo bekommen. in der französischen kindersprache bedeutet bobo einen kleinen schmerz, was wir wewe nennen und ebenso betonen. böhm. ist bobo, bubu ein schreckwort für kinder, unser wauwau, popanz

War Grimms Einschätzung falsch, oder wann wurde aus „Bobo“ ein „Popo“? Liegt der Verschiebung womöglich eine Hyperkorrektion derjenigen Sprecher zugrunde, die B und P ähnlich aussprechen?

Comment: Wenn der Eintrag so stimmt, müsste es teilweise eine doppelte Lautverschiebung gegeben haben, oder? Einmal von Podex zu Bobo, und von da zurück  zu Popo - das finde ich eher unwahrscheinlich. Wahrscheinlicher finde ich, dass es zu Grimms Zeiten die Popo-Sprecher gab, sie ihm (ihnen) aber nicht bekannt waren - kann das aber leider nicht belegen.

Answer (score 7):

Im [Etymologischen Wörterbuch (Wolfgang Pfeifer)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Po) liest man:

> **Podex** *m.* Gesäß, Hintern, Entlehnung (um 1600) von gleichbed. *lat.* pōdex, eigentlich ‘Furzer’, Substantivbildung zu lat. pēdere ‘furzen’. Zunächst wohl, vermittelt durch Lateinschulen, als euphemistischer Ausdruck in dt. Texten. Daraus verkürzt mit nachfolgender Verdoppelung **Popo** *m.* kindersprachlich (2. Hälfte 18. Jh.). Erneute euphemistische Kürzung ergibt **Po** (20. Jh.).

Demnach handelt es sich beim **Popo** um eine Lautverdopplung, wie sie in der [Kindersprache nicht ungewöhnlich ist](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2619/woher-kommt-der-ausdruck-teita-gehen), die in der 2. Hälfte des 18. Jahrhunderts aufgekommen war. Davon wieder euphemistisch gekürzt stammt unser heutiger **Po**.

Je nach Dialekt wird das *P* aber auch weich, wie ein *B* ausgesprochen, von daher die Grimm'sche Variante *Bobo*.

Comment: Also gehen wir davon aus, Grimms Behauptung sei schlicht falsch gewesen?

Comment: So falsch sind die Grimm's nicht, wenn man davon absieht, dass wir heute fast ausschließlich *Popo* schreiben, aber je nachdem wo wir aufgewachsen sind immer noch *Bobo* sagen.

Comment: das ist mir bewußt. Allerdings interpretiere ich Grimms Kommentar so, daß er nur die Variante mit B je hörte. Gehen Sie davon aus, daß immer „Popo“ von „Podex“ gemeint war, das Wort aber in Gegenden aufkam, wo B und P verschwimmen? Interessant ist, daß Grimm einen Bezug zur Ammensprache, nicht aber zur Gelehrtensprache herstellte. Vielleicht war letzterer offensichtlich?

Answer (score 3):

Ich stimme [Takkats Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/43147/1487) zu, möchte dazu aber noch etwas ergänzen:

Die Unterscheidung der Fortis/Lenis-Paare p/b, t/d und k/g ist regional sehr unterschiedlich ausgeprägt. Im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums (ich spreche ganz konkret vom Osten Österreichs, weil ich dort lebe), ist sie so schwach ausgeprägt, dass kaum noch ein Unterschied zu hören ist. Die harten Konsonanten p, t und k werden hier generell eher wie b, d, und g ausgesprochen. Ganz besonders fällt mir das in der Metropolregion Wien auf, wo z.B. der *»Teppich«* als [ˈdɛːbɪç] (also wie *»Deebich«*) ausgesprochen wird.

Gerade beim Paar p/b ist in Österreich kaum ein Unterschied zu hören. Wenn ein Österreicher die folgenden Minimalpaare ausspricht, hört es sich an, als würde er zweimal dasselbe Wort sagen:

- backen - packen
- Gebäck - Gepäck
- Bass - Pass
- Blatt - platt

Das manifestiert sich vor allem bei Eigennamen: Wenn ein Österreicher zu jemandem, der seinen Namen notieren will, sagt: »Ich heiße Grauper« kommt mit Sicherheit die Frage »Mit weichem oder harten B?« (wobei mit dem harten B das P gemeint ist), weil aus der Aussprache nicht klar geschlossen werden kann, welcher Konsonant wirklich gemeint ist. (In der Phrase »mit hartem oder weichem B« steht das B sogar für beide Laute zugleich.)
Anderes Beispiel (diesmal für t/d): Adolf Hitlers Großvater (der Vater seines Vaters) hieß Hiedler.

Neben Eigennamen besteht auch bei umgangssprachlichen Ausdrücken Unsicherheit bezüglich der Schreibweise dieser Konsonanten. Ein in Österreich gängiges Wort für die Ausübung des Geschlechtsverkehrs ist *»pudern«*, das aber von *»buttern«* abstammt. (Ein im alpinen Raum sehr verbreitetes Gerät zur Butterherstellung war das [Stoßbutterfass](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfass): Es hatte an einer Seite ein Loch und wurde mit Rahm gefüllt. Durch das Loch wurde ein Stößel eingeführt, mit dem im Fass eine Siebplatte auf und ab bewegt werden konnte. Durch schnelles und ausdauerndes Ein- und Ausbewegen dieses Stößels wurde im Fass der Rahm zu Butter gestoßen.)
Das *p* in *»pudern«* ist ein ganz klarer Fall einer Hyperkorrektur, wie sie in der Frage erwähnt wurde.

Ausdrücke aus der Kindersprache sind aber genau solche umgangssprachliche Begriffe, die man zwar häufig in der gesprochenen Sprache verwendet, aber selten aufschreibt oder zu lesen bekommt. Daher ist die Assoziation des gesprochenen Wortes mit einem Schriftbild nur schwach ausgeprägt.

Der *»Popo«* gehört da ganz klar dazu. In Österreich wird er als [boˈboː] ausgesprochen. Was eigentlich die Schreibweise *»Bobo«* oder gar *»Boboh«* rechtfertigen würde. Aber wegen der Beinahegleichheit von p und b ist hierzulande auch die Schreibweise *»Popo«* akzeptabel, denn auch sie passt (zumindest im Osten Osterreichs) zur Aussprache [boˈboː]. Die Hyperkorrektur *b→p* ist in Österreich so gängig, dass sie eigentlich kaum noch auffällt.

Dass diese Ähnlichkeit von B und P auch in anderen Regionen existiert, belegt z.B. das Wort

> Alptraum, Albtraum

das auch heute noch in beiden Schreibweisen in den Wörterbüchern steht.

Comment: Nun begreife ich endlich, warum ein Lehrer Ärger bekam, als er sagte, eine Schülerin sehe aus „wie vom wilden Affen gepudert“! Man hat uns erklärt, das sei eine Beschimpfung, aber begriffen hatte ich es nicht..

Comment: Alp/Alb passt wegen der Auslautverhärtung in anderen Teilen unseres Sprachraums nicht ganz als Beispiel.

Comment: Die Frage war doch (soweit ich das verstanden habe), ob zu Grimms Zeiten wirklich gar kein Deutschsprecher Popo mit hartem B gesprochen hat. Insofern finde ich Deine Antwort wie so oft einerseits sehr informativ, aber auch irgendwie an der eigentlichen Frage vorbei. Oder habe ich die konkrete Antwort nur überlesen?

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Wie im ersten Satz ausdrücklich erwähnt, habe ich meinen Beitrag als Ergänzung zu Takkats Antwort gepostet. Leider ist dieser Text aber zu lang, um ihn als Kommentar zu posten. Daher entschied ich mich, ihn als Antwort zu veröffentlichen. Andere Möglichkeiten gibt es hier ja leider nicht. Aber auch wenn ich nicht explizit auf Grimm eingegangen bin, so habe ich mich in meiner Antwort doch mit dem zweiten Teil der Frage, nämlich der Hyperkorrektur beschäftigt, die wiederum von Takkat links liegen gelassen wurde (ohne das ihm das jemand ankreiden würde).