# When can I use "Behüten" as a noun?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> An Silvester war ich mit Aufräumen und `Behüten` meiner Kinder sehr beschäftigt. Ich habe im Internet gesurft und den Spiegel gelesen.

On New Year's Day I was busy taking care of the kids and cleaning the house. I surfed on the web and read der Spiegel.

Someone told me it is strange to use *Behüten* in this context and he didn't give me an explanation. When can I use *Behüten* as a noun and in what context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not mentioning, that "jmd. behüten" indeed sounds a bit sophisticated, one could also say poetic, it is a very good question that can easy be generally answered.

You can put (almost) any verb in a noun form. Often you also have a concrete nominalization, but the other form isn't wrong in all contexts. Let me give an example

> Er liebt den **Umgang** mit Kindern, deshalb blüht er beim (bei dem)
>   **Behüten** seiner eigenen so auf. Das **Betreuen** Anderer ist ihm ein
>   Leichtes. Das **Spielen**, **Rennen**, **Herumalbern** und auf Bäume **Klettern** wohnt
>   ihm noch immer inne.

```
mit jmd. umgehen - der Umgang (Das Umgehen is possible in certain Situation like "Das Umgehen einer Anordnung")
jmd. behüten - das Behüten
jmd. betreuen - das Betreuen (Die Betreuung exists but is more often used as the person, who cares)
spielen - das Spielen
rennen - das Rennen
herumalbern - das Herumalbern
klettern - das Klettern
```

Another situation where nominalization can be used is to imitate the english present progressive. Be carefull it often sounds strange, but is not wrong.

> I'm right now caring for the kids. Ich bin gerade am **Behüten** der
>   Kinder. (Sounds really strange)

but

> I'm tidying up my room. Ich bin am **Aufräumen** meines Zimmers.
>   (Sounds good)

Answer (score 4):

**Behüten** as a noun is very rarely used. For my ears it sounds a little old and over sophisticated. Better use something like **auf meine Kinder aufpassen** or **um meine Kinder kümmern**. So in this sentence that would be

**An Silvester war ich sehr beschäftigt damit, auf meine Kinder aufzupassen und aufzuräumen.**

or even better

**An Silvester hatte ich alle Hände voll zu tun, mich um meine Kinder zu kümmern und aufzuräumen.**

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can use every verb as a noun in certain contexts in German. The nominal character of nominalised verbs becomes clearer if you use definite articles. Furthermore, in your case, i would use `Hüten` instead of `Behüten`:

> An Silvester war ich mit Aufräumen und (dem) Hüten meiner Kinder sehr beschäftigt.

Answer (score 1):

> An Silvester war ich mit `a`ufräumen und `dem` `b`ehüten meiner Kinder sehr beschäftigt. Ich habe im Internet gesurft und den Spiegel gelesen.

The word `Behüten` is best used within the context of "taking care/guarding/protecting/watching over" somebody and/or something really precious to you, like children or material valuables.

I personally wouldn't use it in the context of materialism. Also there are different angles to be considered, using languages/words/expressions: `Behüten` is one of many words in German language, that one rarely hears nowadays, compared to equivalent equals, even though; if you know about the meaning and also can articulate the same sentence "like above" with other efficient words then it is fairly good and acceptable to use, since it only enriches the [use of] language (:

Comment: Why do you spell "aufräumen" and "behüten" with a lower letter (and highlight those at the same time)? Especially after adding an article to "Behüten", it's obvious that there's a capital letter necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about the German verb behüten I find no other use than in religious context.

- Gott behüte dich/ Behüt dich Gott is a pious wish formula. I think English Goodbye 
  is related. I take it that this bye is a remainder of something like German behüten.
  Of course, good in goodbye was God.
- In [Bavarian "Behüt dich Gott" becomes Pfüidi](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/254/woher-kommt-pfiat-di-pfiat-eich-als-abschiedsformel-im-bayerischen-raum). (I should write it in phonetic script, 
  in Latin script the pronunciation is not exact.)
- The German noun Obhut is also a word that belongs to the word family hüten/behüten. It is hardly used in spoken language.